# How gconfd-2 and dconf-service are started in Gnome3 or other gnome-based desktop environments?

Tags: xorg, gnome, d-bus

I want to know, at what moment and by what means the gnome2 and gnome3 configuration daemons, `gconfd-2` and `dconf-service` are started?

Examples of the possible means:

- init scripts
- Xsession.d scripts
- .desktop files
- dbus activation via .service file (in this case, who triggers their startup and how)

[Documentation of dconf says](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-service.html), that dconf-service is started by dbus. Which process triggers its activation and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dconf-service` is automatically started by the session daemon<sup>1</sup> when needed, as per the same documentation page:

```
Users or administrators should never need to start the service, as it will 
be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) whenever an application tries to
write settings.
Reading values from the dconf database does not involve the service;
it is only needed for writes.
```

The service file is `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/ca.desrt.dconf.service`. You can easily see that it's only started when an app tries to write settings if, after a fresh boot into gnome desktop, you open a terminal and run:

```
journalctl -f
```

now if you launch an app that tries to write settings, like `gedit`, the session daemon will report:

```
/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[504]: Activating service name='org.gnome.gedit'
/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[504]: Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.gedit'
/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[502]: Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf'
/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[502]: Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
```

You could also monitor the service with:

```
gdbus monitor --session --dest=ca.desrt.dconf
```

```
Monitoring signals from all objects owned by ca.desrt.dconf
The name ca.desrt.dconf is owned by :1.45
```

and do something, e.g. *gnome-shell* - add some apps to *Favorites*, to see the details: object path, destination, signal (e.g. signal was `Notify` on `ca.desrt.dconf.Writer` interface) etc:

```
/ca/desrt/dconf/Writer/user: ca.desrt.dconf.Writer.Notify ('/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps', [''], ':1.45:user:42')
/ca/desrt/dconf/Writer/user: ca.desrt.dconf.Writer.Notify ('/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps', [''], ':1.45:user:43')
/ca/desrt/dconf/Writer/user: ca.desrt.dconf.Writer.Notify ('/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps', [''], ':1.45:user:44')
/ca/desrt/dconf/Writer/user: ca.desrt.dconf.Writer.Notify ('/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps', [''], ':1.45:user:45')
```

---

*1. The per-session daemon is used for various interprocess communication among desktop applications.*